# How to get count in google datastore objects using php api

Tags: php, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I need to get count of entities in google data store. But I cannot find how in their api. Does anyone know method or a hack to get count using php api?

```
use Google\Cloud\Datastore\DatastoreClient;

$datastore = new DatastoreClient();

$query = $datastore->query();
$query->kind('Companies');
$query->filter('companyName', '=', 'Google');

$res = $datastore->runQuery($query);
$count = 0;
foreach ($res as $company) {
    $count++;
}
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a native count function in the query language since it isn't a scale operation for the server. You can emulate via the client library though in a manner very similar to your code above. If you change it to 'Keys Only' it will be faster and cost less:

```
$datastore = new DatastoreClient();

$query = $datastore->query();
$query->kind('Companies');
$query->filter('companyName', '=', 'Google');

$query->keysOnly();

$res = $datastore->runQuery($query);
$count = 0;
foreach ($res as $company) {
    $count++;
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: Is there a way to access statistics using php sdk?